# How to right align a div within a table cell without wrapping?

Tags: html, css

Peculiar requirements that I couldn't come up with a proper solution for:

For content in a table cell with a `<div>` appended, how can I right align that `<div>` while preventing the whole cell from wrapping?

Here's what I have for consideration: https://jsfiddle.net/c01y63k1/

```css
table td:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table td:first-child > div {
  margin-left: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2>This works:</h2>
<table style="width: 200px">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test test
      <div>
        float!
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Div with a lot of content</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>But...</h2>
<p>
Now my 'float!' is not right-aligned when there's extra space in the cell:
</p>

<table style="width: 500px">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test test
      <div>
        float!
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Div with a lot of content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the above will work when the table cell's automatic width would be less than that of the content's unwrapped width. However, when the table cell's width is larger than that of the content, the `div` will not be right aligned (because it isn't).

Applying `float: right` on the `div` will work in a reverse fashion to the above cases. See that here: https://jsfiddle.net/ycutor3t/

```css
table td:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table td:first-child > div {
  margin-left: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<h2>This does not work:</h2>
<table style="width: 200px">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test test
      <div>
        float!
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Div with a lot of content</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>But... this does!</h2>
<p>
Now my 'float!' is right-aligned when there's extra space in the cell:
</p>

<table style="width: 500px">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test test
      <div>
        float!
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Div with a lot of content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add an [mcve] to your question. If those links stop working for any reason, the question becomes incomplete and impossible to answer.

Comment: Its not floating, because you are simply not floating it, you just add a margin to the left. Anyways, what you want might not work if you don't wrap the "test test" text as well.

Comment: I realize that. I also had the code where a `float:right` is applied. Unfortunately, it will wrap when the cell's width is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox

```css
td:first-child {
  display: flex;
}
td:first-child > div {
  margin-left: auto; /* Push it to the right */
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 500px">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test test
      <div>float!</div>
    </td>
    <td>Div with a lot of content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not ideal to change the table cell to `display: flex`, but I guess I can wrap the contents in a `div` instead and apply the style rule to that.

Comment: @KevinLee Yes, it's a bit weird. But it should behave well, an anonymous table cell will be created, wrapping the `td` flex container.